# Deleting notifications from postgres message queue

Tags: postgresql

I have a functionality where I have a table where for each insert I have to notify a channel with a JSON . I am using `pg_notify` in a trigger function to do that. Now I have to manage that message queue so that if its size reaches 80% it have to delete older messages till it reaches to 50%. I have searched online for it but I havent received any answers. Can any one help.

I am using below mentioned trigger for notifying.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION action_notify() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    action_json    TEXT;
BEGIN
    RAISE DEBUG 'begin: action_notify';
    action_json    := '{"action": "'||NEW.action||'"
                         "action_params": "'||NEW.action_params||'"}';

    PERFORM pg_notify(TG_TABLE_NAME, action_json);
    RAISE DEBUG 'end: action_notify';
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It will be great help if someone can guide me how to manage this message queue. I am not using any other message queue like rabbitmq ...just managing it from postgres..whats the best way to implement this.

Using PostgreSQL 9.3.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: you can't do that with `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`. It's a reliable-delivery queue, and there's no facility for purging old entries.

Instead of passing the message as a notification payload, you should probably insert it into a table, then just `NOTIFY` that the table has changed. You can manage the size of the table with periodic jobs to truncate old entries.